Streamlit script stop running when clicking anywher on the page
Good Morning everyone,
I am currently working on a Generative AI application using Streamlit and FastAPI.
I am facing a problem when running the generative part. My Streamlit webpage shows me that the application is in "running" mode. But if I click anywhere on the site, it starts running in the background.
Can you explain to me what the problem might be, please?
Here is the state of my application.

If I change the page in my application or clic anywhere it continue running on background without showing the result.

where is the code? -> preferably a minimal reproducible example.


Streamlit offers st.session_state to store variables that persist
across to rerun the whole application. You can store the generative
model’s state so that reruns do not disrupt it.


Thank you for your answer. I used the st.session_state to save the state of my variables. The problem is during inference, If I change move to anotehr page of my application or clic somewhere, the model still running but never show the result
